# Scaled Nightmare & Stormwind Champion interaction

Tags: hearthstone

How do Scaled Nightmare and Stormwind Champion interact?

[image]
[image]

Does the Champion's buff get incorporated in the Nightmare's effect, or does the dragon's effect work on the base value, with the +1 from the Champion getting added afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a Stormwind Champion on board, the Scaled Nightmare will come out as a 3/9. Assuming nothing happens to the minions on the next turn, the attack doubles and the Scaled Nightmare is a 6/9. If you then trade off your Champion the Nightmare drops to 5/8.

Similarly you can use attack buffs to also double, e.g. casting Nightmare + Cold Blood puts a 6/8 on board, which turns into a 12/8 the next turn.

As shown in the video @Rob provided, despite many strange occurences with Scaled Nightmare, it works with aura effects as I originally described.

Comment: Have you actually tested this? Scaled Nightmare's effect tends to do unintuitive things.

Comment: Cold Blood is a permanent effect, that can be removed only by silencing the dragon (and that also removes the card effect, returning it to the basic 2 attack). Stormwind champion's effect instead is an aura, so its effects may not be so straightforward. As Studoku asked, have you actually tried this interaction?

Comment: I always assumed that auras as mentioned were applied last, so the doubling would be to 4 then the +1 would be added. then to 8 with the +1 added after again

Comment: I didn't test this exact case, but in a brawl i once had stormwind champion and Gahz'rilla and Gahz attack doubled based upon the buffed value, when it was damaged. The mechanic should be exactly the same.

Comment: The mechanic should be the same, but that is not the case. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePmc3SRT_TE At 3:30, approximately, there is a comparison to minions with similar effect including Gahz'rilla.

Comment: @Rob Well, the video shows, the mechanic in regards to aura effects, i.e. stormwind champion or the example provided in the video dire wolf is exactly as I described it in my answer.

Comment: Hi Dulkan, can you re-test Scaled Nightmare? It got fixed in Patch 5.0.0.13030, and may no longer have the unusual interaction with Stormwind Champion (we'd expect it to work like Gahz'rilla vs Stormwind Champion now).